# Functional tabs which look like a btn-group

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

My goal here is to make these tabs work and keep the `btn-group` visual style.

However, it doesn't seem to work unless I completely change the structure of the `content_navigation` (using `<ul>` and `<li>` instead of a `<div>` containing the links), which makes the tabs look completely different.

It looks like I have to choose between having functional tabs or having a good looking `btn-group`. I'm sure there is a way to get both, but I couldn't figure out how.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Tab test</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div id="content_navigation" class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <a type="button" href="#content_1" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> To 1</a>
      <a type="button" href="#content_1" class="btn btn-default hidden"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> To 1 again</a>
      <a type="button" href="#content_1" class="btn btn-default hidden"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> To 1 again, and again</a>
      <a type="button" href="#content_2" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> To 2</a>
      <a type="button" href="#content_3" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> To 3</a>
      <a type="button" href="#content_4" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> To 4</a>
    </div>
    <div id="content_1">
      Content n°1
    </div>
    <div id="content_2">
      Content n°2
    </div>
    <div id="content_3">
      Content n°3
    </div>
    <div id="content_4">
      Content n°4
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#content_navigation").tabs();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `data-toggle="tab"` in all `#content_navigation a` and class `tab-pane` for all `div` having contents

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Tab test</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div id="content_navigation" class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="" role="tablist">
      <a type="button" href="#content_1" class="btn btn-default" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> To 1</a>
      <a type="button" href="#content_1" class="btn btn-default hidden" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> To 1 again</a>
      <a type="button" href="#content_1" class="btn btn-default hidden" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> To 1 again, and again</a>
      <a type="button" href="#content_2" class="btn btn-default" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> To 2</a>
      <a type="button" href="#content_3" class="btn btn-default" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> To 3</a>
      <a type="button" href="#content_4" class="btn btn-default" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> To 4</a>
    </div>
    
     <div class="tab-content">
       <div id="content_1" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active">
      Content n°1
    </div>
    <div id="content_2" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane">
      Content n°2
    </div>
    <div id="content_3" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane">
      Content n°3
    </div>
    <div id="content_4" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane">
      Content n°4
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#content_navigation").tabs();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```